# Printing the sorted elements of a matrix in descending order with array indices in the fastest fashion

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

This seems like a simple problem but I am having trouble doing this in a fast manner.

Say I have a matrix and I want to sort this matrix and store the indices of the elements in descending order. Is there a quick way to do this? Right now, I am extracting the maximum, storing the result, changing it to -2, and then extracting the next maximum in a for loop. Which is probably the most inefficient way to do it.

My problem actually requires me to work on a 20,000 X 20,000 matrix. Memory is not an issue. Any ideas about the fastest way to do it would be great.

For example if I have a matrix

```
>m<-matrix(c(1,4,2,3),2,2)
>m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    4    3
```

I want the result to indicate the numbers in descending order:

```
 row  col val
 2    1   4
 2    2   3
 1    2   2
 1    1   1
```

Comment: A matrix is just a vector with a `dim` attribute. Can't you just do `order(m)` or `sort(m)`? I'm not sure regarding the desired output. Also, you can  reduce the problem to just `m<- matrix(runif(100),10,10)` for convenience and it is preferable to use `set.seed` when providing an example using `runif`

Comment: Edited the question with regard to the desired result. I just need the indices of the elements in descending order of a matrix. If i do `sort(m)` I lose the index information because it gets converted to a vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a possible `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
rows <- nrow(m) ; cols <- ncol(m)
res <- data.table(
                  row = rep(seq_len(rows), cols), 
                  col = rep(seq_len(cols), each = rows),
                  val = c(m)
)
setorder(res, -val)
res
#    row col val
# 1:   2   1   4
# 2:   2   2   3
# 3:   1   2   2
# 4:   1   1   1
```

---

**Edit**: a base R alternative

```
res <- cbind(
        row = rep(seq_len(rows), cols), 
        col = rep(seq_len(cols), each = rows),
        val = c(m)
)    
res[order(-res[, 3]),]
#      row col val
# [1,]   2   1   4
# [2,]   2   2   3
# [3,]   1   2   2
# [4,]   1   1   1
```

Comment: Installing packages in my cluster near impossible and I was hoping for a solution based on the default packages, but this definitely does work. Thanks.

Comment: It is easy enough to achieve the same with base R too, see my edit. I wonder how this scales or your huge data though.

Comment: This is so weird. When i tried the base version of the example, I wasnt getting the right results, so i tried an example. 
 
`net<-matrix(runif(600*600),600,600)
rows <- nrow(net)
cols <- ncol(net)
res <- cbind(
        row = rep(seq_len(rows), cols), 
        col = rep(seq_len(cols), each = rows),
        val = c(net)
) 
res[order(-res[, 3]),]`

Clearly you can see in res[1:10,] that it is not in any order. I tried it with different seeds with runif(). I have no idea why this is not working.

Comment: Did you rerun `rows <- nrow(net) ; cols <- ncol(net)` too? Or just used the previous ones?

Comment: I reran everything. It doesnt seem to work for the 600 x 600 matrix.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What exactly isn't working? Also, when using `runif` you need to `set.seed` before it, in order to be able to reproduce its results

Comment: `set.seed(1023);
net<-matrix(runif(600*600),600,600);
rows <- nrow(net);
cols <- ncol(net);
res <- cbind(
        row = rep(seq_len(rows), cols), 
        col = rep(seq_len(cols), each = rows),
        val = c(net)
) ;
res[order(-res[, 3]),] `   

And I tried to see the first 5 results to see if it was sorting right. 
`res[1:5,]`
this is what i get.
` row col       val
[1,]   1   1 0.2493580
[2,]   2   1 0.2529563
[3,]   3   1 0.9496766
[4,]   4   1 0.4891691
[5,]   5   1 0.4063322 
`
It doesn't seem like it is sorting based on the third column.

Comment: Of course it didn't work, as you didn't store the ordered result anywhere. Try `res2 <- res[order(-res[, 3]),] ; res2[1:5,]`. This works with `data.table` without the `<-` operator because `setorder` modifies the data *in place*. It's just `data.table` magic

Comment: Shouldn't the order() function change that order internally in original res variable?

Comment: No it shouldn't. No function in base R does, so why `order` will be an exception?