# Converting a matrix to a data.table list format

Tags: r, data.table

I was wondering whether it is possible to do the following in data.table. Suppose I have a matrix `mat = matrix(data=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), nrow=3, ncol=3)` and I would like to construct:

```
row col value
1   1   1
1   2   4
1   3   7
...
```

Now my problem is that I would like to do this during my construction of the data.table, but I am not sure how to start.

```
data.table(row = c(1:nrow(mat)), col = c(1:ncol(mat)), v = c(1:(ncol(mat)*ncol(mat))))
```

This does not give me the correct format, because the row and column columns are the same.

Thanks

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631181/printing-the-sorted-elements-of-a-matrix-in-descending-order-with-array-indices/30631869#30631869) helps? (assuming your matrix called `m` instead of `mat`)

Comment: Hmm... my question then seems like a duplicate. Thank you David!